# Combobox gets closed on MessageBox closure ZK

Tags: combobox, messagebox, zk

I'm using ZK CE-9.0.0.

I have a `combobox` which I need to open programmatically, on click of `OK` button of the `Messagebox`. Hence I have implemented a `Listener` for the click event of the `OK` button. Inside the click event, I'm opening the `combobox` by using the following code:

```
EventListener<Messagebox.ClickEvent> clickListener = new EventListener<Messagebox.ClickEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ClickEvent event) throws Exception {
        mycombo.open();
    }
};
Messagebox.Button[] buttons = new Messagebox.Button[] {Messagebox.Button.OK};
Messagebox.show("Hi btn", buttons, clickListener);
```

Now the problem that I'm facing is, the `combobox` opens for half a second. It then immediately gets closed automatically.

As per my understanding, it's because of the `Messagebox`. Once the execution of the click event is completed, the `Messagebox` is closed & it causes the `combobox` also to be closed.

Please have a look at [this](https://zkfiddle.org/sample/1rkm5d/3-Combobox-gets-closed-on-MessageBox-close#source-2) fiddler for better understanding. **Please select the ZK version to be 9.0.0 before running it.**

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks,

RAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the main issue comes from the button retrieving focus after the animation of the combobox.
The focus is given back to the button by the closed messagebox
Since the combobox loose focus, the combo popup is also closed.

A clean way to handle this would be to use an [echo event](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/UI_Patterns/Long_Operations/Use_Echo_Events) to wait for the messagebox to be actually closed before sending the open action to the combobox.
See this fiddle:
https://zkfiddle.org/sample/1rkm5d/6-Combobox-gets-closed-on-MessageBox-close#source-2